# Recreating the TextBox control

Tags: c#

I want to recreate the TextBox, from scratch. No overriding, etc. I don't care how hard it is, or how long it will take.

---

I have been searching for information about this, but haven't found anything, yet. Are there any documents that you know of? Or, how (are we even allowed) would we 'see' how the TextBox in Windows was written? Can we use Object Browser for that in Visual Studio?

I'd also like to know if anybody else has done this before, and if there is anything that I *should know* before I begin my endeavor.

Comment: is this wpf or winforms?

Comment: To what level do you not want to override? Are you going to be building a new operating system to support this? What is your purpose? Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: you can use a decompiler to see how the TextBox was written. .Net Reflector is good. http://www.reflector.net/

Comment: @TejasSharma - That's a great question; one that I overlooked while writing the question. My answer to your question would be (sorry if it is vague) "Whatever the native TextBox is that is used in the Windows OS" - if that doesn't help, then I'll go with WinForms for now.

Comment: The textbox control is serviced by windows' internals. .Net control is only adding sugar around this.

Comment: Where does the windows os use a .net textbox?

Comment: @Curt - Nope. No operating system - yet. It is something I've been studying; but that's irrelevant to why I want to write a TextBox. I want to write a TextBox because I am really bored with what I can already do and I think that if I do something that I have absolutely no idea about, it'll keep me from getting bored and I'll also learn alot along the way.

Comment: @Zeph - Thanks for the link. Sorry, I'll edit .net out of the tags. My mistake.

Comment: You can actually find source code for Microsoft's WPF controls. Here's a link to TextBox's implementation http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/Dotnetfx_Win7_3@5@1/3@5@1/DEVDIV/depot/DevDiv/releases/Orcas/NetFXw7/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBox@cs/1/TextBox@cs

Comment: Um, EH? That's all there is to the WPF textbox? I thought it would be like a trillion lines of code :-/ (thanks for the link)

Comment: I didn't realize a textbox control was thousands of lines of code..

Answer (score 2):

**Are there any documents that you know of?**  Many, but I'd assume you mean documents about how the TextBox works.  The best you'll get there is the MSDN documentation.

**How would we 'see' how the TextBox in Windows was written?** Use a decompiler like Jetbrains DotPeek, or Telerik's JustDecompile.

**Has anyone done this before?**  Almost certainly not.  What would be the value?

Comment: No value, really. Probably a complete waste of time; though I think it will help me out a lot. I like to learn how things really work, and the easiest way for me to learn this stuff is to recreate it (or atleast try).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you know where I could find the TextBox DLL in Windows? I searched for it but couldn't find anything even remotely close, I'm guessing it may not be in its own DLL file?

Comment: From the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.aspx) you can see that the WPF textbox is in assembly `PresentationFramework.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to check out MSDN's information on creating custom controls.  A quick Google search for '.NET custom Controls' should get you on your way.  [MSDN Links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6hws6h2t.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I recall reading years ago about this product, where the author re-wrote (or at least, re-jigged) the available controls - in his case, for security purposes (eg making sure passwords weren't exposed in RAM, etc, for the life of the control).

This is all open source, so might be something useful here.  Documentation about the how/whys of it all were on the site back then, too.

[KeePass Password Safe](http://keepass.info/)